# Stop google from translating HTML attributes

Tags: html, google-translate

I am using google translate API and facing the following problem, the API translates the content as well as the HTML attributes.

E.g

`<span class="step-number two">2</span>`

Is translated to in Dutch

`<span class = "stap-nummer twee"> 2 </ span>`

I don't want my **class attributes** to be translated as It well mess up all the styling of my page. Is there a way to do so.?

Using 'google-translate' (Google Translate API for Node.js)

E.g

`googleTranslate.translate('Hello', 'de', function(err, translation) {
  console.log(translation);
  // =>  { translatedText: 'Hallo', originalText: 'Hello', detectedSourceLanguage: 'en' }
});`

Where in place of 'Hello' , I provide my HTML

Comment: please show some code to demonstrate how you are going about this

Comment: I am using google translate API. using nodeJs , https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate.

Comment: you could improve your question further by including example code that demonstrates your problem; at the moment, as I understand it, it is the HTML that you pass in place of Hello that doesn't get translated as you want it to, therefore why don't you show an real example of what you are passing in and what is coming out and detail what you want to be different?

Comment: Sorry, I missed my E.G , correcting my question, Now It's good to go